# Find the count of shared account

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table below called ***acc_table***:

| name | account_id |
| --- | --- |
| john | 1234 |
| john | 5678 |
| lisa | 1234 |
| lisa | 3345 |

And i want to write a SQL query to generate the below table, to find the count of share accounts and the corresponding account owner:

| person_1 | person_2 | count_of_shared_account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | lisa | 1 |

The closest approach i have is:

```
SELECT a1.name AS person_1, a2.name AS person_2, COUNT(a1.account_id) AS count_of_shared_account
FROM acc_table a1
JOIN acc_table a2
ON a1.account_id = a2.account_id
AND a1.name != a2.name
GROUP BY 1,2
```

The result i got is:

| person_1 | person_2 | count_of_shared_account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | lisa | 1 |
| lisa | john | 1 |

Which the second row is a repeated result of the first row and i don't want that.

What is the correct approach to solve this problem and get the table we want? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you expect if there was a third of fourth etc person sharing an account_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit this to one row per tuple by changing

```
AND a1.name != a2.name
```

to

```
AND a1.name < a2.name
```

So when you have `Lisa,John` and `John,Lisa` for `a1.Name,a2.Name` then `Lisa,John` will be excluded since `Lisa > John`.

**Full Query**

```
SELECT a1.name AS person_1, a2.name AS person_2, COUNT(a1.account_id) AS count_of_shared_account
FROM acc_table a1
JOIN acc_table a2
ON a1.account_id = a2.account_id
AND a1.name < a2.name
GROUP BY a1.name, a2.name;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f8bc6/1)**

If you have multiple people sharing an account you'll get a row for each tuple, e.g. if you had 3 people (Lisa, John and Steve), you'll get 3 rows:

| person_1 | person_2 | count_of_shared_account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | lisa | 1 |
| john | Steve | 1 |
| lisa | Steve | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

You can consider this:

Metadata Creation:

```
Create table acc_table(name varchar(20), account_id int);
Insert into acc_table values('John',123);
Insert into acc_table values('Lisa',123);
Insert into acc_table values('Tiger',567);
Insert into acc_table values('Lisa',567);
Insert into acc_table values('Lisa',890);
Insert into acc_table values('Tiger',890);
Insert into acc_table values('max',111);
Insert into acc_table values('lucy',222);
Insert into acc_table values('monica',222);
Insert into acc_table values('Jenifer',222);
Insert into acc_table values('lucy',333);
Insert into acc_table values('monica',333);
Insert into acc_table values('Jenifer',333);
Insert into acc_table values('lucy',444);
Insert into acc_table values('monica',444);
Insert into acc_table values('Jenifer',444);
```

Query below will produce the result as shown

```
With BaseData (members,account_id) as
(
Select group_concat(name) members, Account_id
from 
(Select *, row_number() over ( partition by account_id order by name ) rnum 
from acc_table) a
group by account_id
order by rnum
)
select members, count(account_id) Count_of_Shared_Accounts
from BaseData
group by members;
```

Results:

```
members             | Count_of_Shared_Accounts
:------------------ | -----------------------:
max                 |                        1
John,Lisa           |                        1
Jenifer,lucy,monica |                        3
Lisa,Tiger          |                        2
```

Since MySql does not support PIVOT functionality, it becomes very hard to pivot using workarounds where number of columns are dynamic (same here as we don't know how many members can share an account).

details of dynamically split CSV string into columns (like the final expected output) can be found [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187424/split-column-values-to-multiple-columns-dynamically).